# Why doesn't `style.webKitTransition` and `style.webkitTransform` work anymore in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, webkit, webkit-transform, webkit-transition

These lines:

```
numberElement.style.webkitTransition=".1s ease-in-out";
numberElement.style.webkitTransform="scale(2.0)";
```

100% worked no more than a year ago.  I pulled down the very stale repo to add another feature to it, but when I viewed the page, the scale wasn't working anymore.  I changed my `HEAD` to be right at the commit where I am positive it was working, and the `scale` still doesn't work.

Checking out the elements at runtime, this is what I see

```
<span id="minute-number" style="transition: 0.1s ease-in-out; transform: scale(2.0);">TEST</span>
```

But visually, nothing is happening to the `TEST` text

Did something change with how I need to use `webkitTransition` or `webkitTransform`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it (sort of)
The elements that I was transforming were `<span>` elements, which apparently can't take transforms.

So I changed the css:

```
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

and the transforms were applied.  The issue now is that `inline-block` modifies the dimensions of my elements, which I have asked about here: [Why does applying `inline-block` force dimensions onto my span element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40291856/why-does-applying-inline-block-force-dimensions-onto-my-span-element)

Something must have changed in Chrome, though, because the transforms definitely worked on the `<span>` elements a year ago

Answer (score 2):

I have this question too.
In my situation, sometime I want to scale a element according to devicePixelRatio.So here is my code:

```
var ele = document.getElementById('my-id');
ele.style.transform = 'scale(xxx)';
ele.style.webkitTransform = 'scale(xxx)';
```

It didn't work.
So I console `ele.style` in terminal. As we known, it will console a `CSSStyleDeclaration` object. However, the property `webkitTransform` doesn't show in CSSStyleDeclaration object.
In fact, when you code `ele.style.webkitTransform = xxxx` which not work because of CSSStyleDeclaration object have no property `webkitTransform`.

I find the explanation from official document, [CSS Declaration Blocks](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#parse-a-css-declaration-block). Please attention `parse a CSS declaration block` step3, it looks like the lodash function `_.extend({}, {...})`.

I have another solution, like this:

```
ele.setAttribute('style', ele.style.cssText + '-webkit-transform:scale(1);')
```

Maybe it looks a little ugly, but it work.
Hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks for your answer :) . it's been a longggg time, but when i go back to this project i'll be sure to try it out