# Why does applying `inline-block` force dimensions onto my span element?

Tags: css, display

So I have this `<span>` element, and I wanted to apply a `webkit-transform` to it.  Unfortunately, I have to specify the `display` attribute to be `inline-block` in order for this to work.

```
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

But once I apply this attribute, the entire span shifts.

You'll note that before I set it, the `<span>` element has it's dimensions automatically calculated:
[image]

But once I do set the property, the dimensions are computed, and they are slightly different from what is automatically calculated previously:
[image]

Why does this happen?  Is there a way I can apply `inline-block` without the `<span>` changing dimensions at all?  I can't tell if there's padding/margins or whatever being applied but it definitely is moving

Comment: inline-block,makes span to behave as block element so thats why it will have width and height

Comment: But where does the extra width and height come from?

I have a string of characters, split into spans.  But when I set `inline-block`, the string increases slightly in height and width, as if there was some kind of padding added inbetween the blocks

Comment: when a span is made as inline-block and when no height and width is given,width would be the span's content width and height would be span's content height ,if no content is specified i guess width and height would be 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally changing an element from inline to inline-block will not automatically change its size, even though the computed width and height change from `auto` to numbers.

One thing that's different for `inline-block` elements is that their margins and paddings in all directions are respected, while `inline` elements only have horizontal margins and paddings. So if you set vertical margins/paddings on the `span`, that would explain why it is moving after being changed into `inline-block`.

Otherwise, it's hard to know the answer without seeing the actual page.

Comment: This helped me find the solution.  I had `span` elements everywhere, and had inadvertently changed all of their `display` attributes.  I just set a class on the `span` elements that I wanted to change, and applied the display to that class.  Everything looks as it did before now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As inline-block makes your span to behave as block element it will have
width and height

you may consider using display:flex for this

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.container span:first-child{
   -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<span>
  span1
</span>
<span>
  span2
</span>
</div>
```

Hope this helps